# SQL Query returns Invalid Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am Using Simple Query with IN Operator. I am using following Query

```
SELECT CustID  FROM Customer WHERE CustID in (6,34,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Now it displays Following Order

```
custId  
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
34
```

But I want the result as the same sequence which I pass in the `IN` Clause.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I am Using SQL Server 2008  and i use only this simple Query .

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CustID  FROM Customer WHERE CustID in (6,34,5,4,3,2,1)
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN CustId = 34
               THEN 5.5
               ELSE CustId
          END DESC
```

Comment: Just be prepared for the inevitable slowdown when you try to scale your data :-) This will work fine for most databases since they're relatively small but per-row functions always have a performance impact. However, I won't downvote since it _is_ useful for at least some cases.

Comment: Agree, a nice solution to THIS particular case. In general, I would (and have in my answer :-) ) also recommend a new order column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query Ramdas......

```
SELECT CustID  FROM Customer WHERE CustID in (6,34,5,4,3,2,1) 
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(','+CAST(CustID as varchar(MAX))+',', ',6,34,5,4,3,2,1,')
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL doesn't specify default orders in either `select` statements or `in` clauses. The rows will be returned in whatever order the DBMS wants to.

If you want to force the order to something specific, you need to use an order-by clause.

Some SQL *implementations* may allow this to be configured, but not any of the ones I use regularly. Worst case, you can try something like:

```
select 1 as x, custid from customer where custid = 6
union all select 2 as x, custid from customer where custid = 34
union all select 3 as x, custid from customer where custid = 5
order by x
```

but it's pretty ugly and not overly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if you want that to happen, you will need a new field like 'showorder' or something, on which you can order your result:

```
SELECT CustID FROM Customer WHERE CustID IN (6,34,5,4,3,2,1) ORDER BY showorder
```

Comment: The new field that needs to be added in order to have a non-standard sort order.

Comment: Sure, this is standard SQL. You just add a new field to your table, you can name it whatever you want (I named it 'showorder' here to annotate what the field is used for). In that new field, you put the order of the records in which they should appear. Then you use ORDER BY to sort on that field in ASCending or DEScending order.

Comment: @RamdasBhosale showorder is not an SQL or SQL Server function or anything. It is an extra field that you add to the table yourself.

Comment: @Borniet I usderstand the same after not Finding this. Sorry i am little weak on SQL Serever. But for the simple Query why should i add one more column because the SQL server control is totaly depends on Client side. WE CAN not change anything in the given implementation. Also want to know about there is any other simple way to do this.

Comment: There are other ways to do this, as the other answers on your question here describe. However, none of them are easy, nor performant.

Comment: @Freelancer - Hi. Please don't use non-English language in Stack Overflow. It is [discouraged here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/187824). :)

Comment: @hims056 totally agree with you. but the person is from my community thats why i ought to write in our language, otherwise our regional and religious rules will get violeted.

Comment: @Freelancer - But using non-English language, [you would be limiting your comments' audience to users who speak your native language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176545/187824). So Other users will not benefit from it.

Comment: @hims056 you are absolutely write, thats why i never give any answer in non-english language. and still i know commenting in non-english is also not acceptable, but i am already bound with the rules of my community, thats why i cant speak with him any other language than marathi. I am still agreeying you. but i cant do any thing without saying sorry to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @id TABLE
(
      i INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , id INT
)

INSERT INTO @id (id)
VALUES (6),(34),(5),(4),(3),(2),(1)

SELECT c.CustID  
FROM dbo.Customer c
JOIN @id i ON i.id = c.CustID
ORDER BY i.i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a split string CTE with ordered values. Hence you will be able to sort any of dataset

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100) = '6,34,5,4,3,2,1';
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@test , 0, CHARINDEX( ',', @test)) AS val ,
         CAST(STUFF (@test + ',' , 1, CHARINDEX( ',', @test), '') AS nvarchar(100 )) AS stval,
         1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval , 0, CHARINDEX( ',', stval)),
         CAST(STUFF (stval, 1, CHARINDEX(',' , stval ), '' ) AS nvarchar(100 )),
         [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  SELECT c2.CustID
  FROM dbo.Customer c2 JOIN cte c ON c2.CustID = c.val
  ORDER BY c.[level]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f6d1/2)

Also you can wrap CTE in function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo. SplitStrings_CTE(@List nvarchar( 1000), @Delimiter nvarchar(1 ))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@List , 0 , CHARINDEX (@Delimiter, @List)) AS val ,
         CAST(STUFF (@List + @Delimiter, 1 , CHARINDEX (@Delimiter, @List), '') AS nvarchar (1000)) AS stval, 1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval , 0 , CHARINDEX (@Delimiter, stval)),
         CAST(STUFF (stval , 1, CHARINDEX( @Delimiter , stval ), '' ) AS nvarchar(1000 )), [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  SELECT REPLACE(val , ' ' , '' ) AS val, [level]
  FROM cte
```

SELECT statement with using function

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100) = '6,34,5,4,3,2,1';
SELECT CustID
FROM dbo.Customer c2 JOIN (SELECT val, [level] FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@test, ',')
                           ) c ON c2.CustID = c.val
ORDER BY c.[level]
```

OR

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100) = '6,34,5,4,3,2,1';
SELECT CustID
FROM dbo.Customer c2 CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@test, ',') c                           
WHERE c2.CustID = c.val
ORDER BY c.[level]
```